# Completely fill the circle of radio button

Tags: android, android-studio, radio-button

I know this is a basic question but i cannot find the proper solution. I only want when i click on radio button in fill the entire circle with my own color code. Default behavior is to fill from center not the entire circle.

```
 <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/rb_available"
                android:text="Available"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
```

Comment: please show your java and xml code or any demo type image

Comment: @SamadTalukder here is my code it show radio button with fill from center but not the complete circle fill (default behaviour)